# Como usar o react-native-web?

Tags: react-native

- Como usar o [react-native-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web) ?
- Pra usar o react-native-web (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web) não é só fazer um: `npm install react-native-web react-art`

depois no index adicionar essa parte:

```
// register to react native web
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', {
  rootTag: document.getElementById('root'),
});
```

index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

// register the app
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

// register to react native web
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', {
  rootTag: document.getElementById('root'),
});
```

Depois dar `npm start` na pasta do projeto?

Porque eu fiz isso, mas quando vou no navegador em `localhost:3000`, mostra como se tivesse offline

Será que tá usando outra porta?

Ou eu fiz algo errado?

Ou ta faltando algo?

Comment: Deu certo annety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um caminho antes do êxito para uma solução rodando, [tem um exemplo de como seria um exemplo minimo para rodar](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6) e para funcionar precisa ser criado uma instalação meio manual.

***1)*** Instalar os pacotes para o seu funcionamento:

- [react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react)
- [react-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom)
- [react-native-web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web)
- [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)

da seguinte forma: `yarn add react react-dom react-native-web react-scripts` no seu console.

***2)*** depois da instalação desses pacotes terá no seu projeto uma pasta `node_modules` e ai nesse mesmo diretório crie duas pastas, a `src` e a `public`. Dentro da pasta `public` crie um arquivo `index.html` com o seguinte contéudo:

---

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"> 
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
<style> 
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }   
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #root {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>   
</body>

</html>
```

e dentro da pasta `src` dois arquivo:

- `App.js`

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const logoUri = `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3"><g fill="#61DAFB"><path d="M666.3 296.5c0-32.5-40.7-63.3-103.1-82.4 14.4-63.6 8-114.2-20.2-130.4-6.5-3.8-14.1-5.6-22.4-5.6v22.3c4.6 0 8.3.9 11.4 2.6 13.6 7.8 19.5 37.5 14.9 75.7-1.1 9.4-2.9 19.3-5.1 29.4-19.6-4.8-41-8.5-63.5-10.9-13.5-18.5-27.5-35.3-41.6-50 32.6-30.3 63.2-46.9 84-46.9V78c-27.5 0-63.5 19.6-99.9 53.6-36.4-33.8-72.4-53.2-99.9-53.2v22.3c20.7 0 51.4 16.5 84 46.6-14 14.7-28 31.4-41.3 49.9-22.6 2.4-44 6.1-63.6 11-2.3-10-4-19.7-5.2-29-4.7-38.2 1.1-67.9 14.6-75.8 3-1.8 6.9-2.6 11.5-2.6V78.5c-8.4 0-16 1.8-22.6 5.6-28.1 16.2-34.4 66.7-19.9 130.1-62.2 19.2-102.7 49.9-102.7 82.3 0 32.5 40.7 63.3 103.1 82.4-14.4 63.6-8 114.2 20.2 130.4 6.5 3.8 14.1 5.6 22.5 5.6 27.5 0 63.5-19.6 99.9-53.6 36.4 33.8 72.4 53.2 99.9 53.2 8.4 0 16-1.8 22.6-5.6 28.1-16.2 34.4-66.7 19.9-130.1 62-19.1 102.5-49.9 102.5-82.3zm-130.2-66.7c-3.7 12.9-8.3 26.2-13.5 39.5-4.1-8-8.4-16-13.1-24-4.6-8-9.5-15.8-14.4-23.4 14.2 2.1 27.9 4.7 41 7.9zm-45.8 106.5c-7.8 13.5-15.8 26.3-24.1 38.2-14.9 1.3-30 2-45.2 2-15.1 0-30.2-.7-45-1.9-8.3-11.9-16.4-24.6-24.2-38-7.6-13.1-14.5-26.4-20.8-39.8 6.2-13.4 13.2-26.8 20.7-39.9 7.8-13.5 15.8-26.3 24.1-38.2 14.9-1.3 30-2 45.2-2 15.1 0 30.2.7 45 1.9 8.3 11.9 16.4 24.6 24.2 38 7.6 13.1 14.5 26.4 20.8 39.8-6.3 13.4-13.2 26.8-20.7 39.9zm32.3-13c5.4 13.4 10 26.8 13.8 39.8-13.1 3.2-26.9 5.9-41.2 8 4.9-7.7 9.8-15.6 14.4-23.7 4.6-8 8.9-16.1 13-24.1zM421.2 430c-9.3-9.6-18.6-20.3-27.8-32 9 .4 18.2.7 27.5.7 9.4 0 18.7-.2 27.8-.7-9 11.7-18.3 22.4-27.5 32zm-74.4-58.9c-14.2-2.1-27.9-4.7-41-7.9 3.7-12.9 8.3-26.2 13.5-39.5 4.1 8 8.4 16 13.1 24 4.7 8 9.5 15.8 14.4 23.4zM420.7 163c9.3 9.6 18.6 20.3 27.8 32-9-.4-18.2-.7-27.5-.7-9.4 0-18.7.2-27.8.7 9-11.7 18.3-22.4 27.5-32zm-74 58.9c-4.9 7.7-9.8 15.6-14.4 23.7-4.6 8-8.9 16-13 24-5.4-13.4-10-26.8-13.8-39.8 13.1-3.1 26.9-5.8 41.2-7.9zm-90.5 125.2c-35.4-15.1-58.3-34.9-58.3-50.6 0-15.7 22.9-35.6 58.3-50.6 8.6-3.7 18-7 27.7-10.1 5.7 19.6 13.2 40 22.5 60.9-9.2 20.8-16.6 41.1-22.2 60.6-9.9-3.1-19.3-6.5-28-10.2zM310 490c-13.6-7.8-19.5-37.5-14.9-75.7 1.1-9.4 2.9-19.3 5.1-29.4 19.6 4.8 41 8.5 63.5 10.9 13.5 18.5 27.5 35.3 41.6 50-32.6 30.3-63.2 46.9-84 46.9-4.5-.1-8.3-1-11.3-2.7zm237.2-76.2c4.7 38.2-1.1 67.9-14.6 75.8-3 1.8-6.9 2.6-11.5 2.6-20.7 0-51.4-16.5-84-46.6 14-14.7 28-31.4 41.3-49.9 22.6-2.4 44-6.1 63.6-11 2.3 10.1 4.1 19.8 5.2 29.1zm38.5-66.7c-8.6 3.7-18 7-27.7 10.1-5.7-19.6-13.2-40-22.5-60.9 9.2-20.8 16.6-41.1 22.2-60.6 9.9 3.1 19.3 6.5 28.1 10.2 35.4 15.1 58.3 34.9 58.3 50.6-.1 15.7-23 35.6-58.4 50.6zM320.8 78.4z" /><circle cx="420.9" cy="296.5" r="45.7" /><path d="M520.5 78.1z" /></g></svg>;

const Link = props => (
  <Text
    {...props}
    accessibilityRole="link"
    style={StyleSheet.compose(
      styles.link,
      props.style
    )}
  />
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Image
            accessibilityLabel="React logo"
            source={{ uri: logoUri }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={styles.logo}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title}>React Native for Web</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          This is an example of an app built with{" "}
          <Link href="https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app">
            Create React App
          </Link>{" "}
          and{" "}
          <Link href="https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web">
            React Native for Web
          </Link>
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          To get started, edit{" "}
          <Link href="https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6/" style={styles.code}>
            src/App.js
          </Link>
          .
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Example button" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    maxWidth: 500
  },
  logo: {
    height: 80
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    marginVertical: "1em",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  text: {
    lineHeight: "1.5em",
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    marginVertical: "1em",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  link: {
    color: "#1B95E0"
  },
  code: {
    fontFamily: "monospace, monospace"
  }
});

export default App;
```

- `index.js`

---

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);

AppRegistry.runApplication("App", {
  rootTag: document.getElementById("root")
});
```

basicamente está quase pronto.

***3)*** Organizar o arquivo `package.json` com o seguinte `layout`

```
{
  "name": "react-native",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Native for Web starter template",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

***4)*** Agora rode o comando `yarn start` e sua aplicação subirá o ambiente de teste.

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Código referente a esse exemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6)
- [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)
- [React Native for Web - Getting started](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md)